# Linking to an API

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to access a weather API that shows the icon of current weather. 
My current code is:

```
response = HTTParty.get('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?id=5911606&appid=734d8f2204043326b51df724c5c917f4', format: :json)
body = JSON.parse(response.body)["weather"][0]
@icon=body["icon"]
```

In html i am using the icon like:

```
<%= link_to image_tag('http://openweathermap.org/img/w/' + @icon +".png", :size => '130x130', :style => 'margin-top:45px;'), root_path%>
```

Its working fine when i first starts the server, but as I clicked any other link its gives me the following error:

```
nil is not a valid asset source
```

Does anybody know how to fix this?

Comment: Where does all this code reside?  Is your `@icon` being set in the exact method in the controller?  I find the error interesting because `string + nil` will cause a `TypeError` of "no implicit conversion of nil into String".

Comment: first one is in the main page controller.erb and second one is in the  html file that has the elements regarding main page.

Comment: and you are right it is giving the same error you mentioned but i dont why it is working fine when i first runs the server

Comment: You're not really answering the question.  Post the complete controller code and we can probably help.

Answer (score 0):

it seems you are getting an empty @icon object. you can check for for empty icon object with `@icon.blank?` like following

```
<%= link_to image_tag('http://openweathermap.org/img/w/' + @icon +".png", :size => '130x130', :style => 'margin-top:45px;'), root_path unless @icon.blank? %>
```

if you can also think if having a helper method to display a default icon if the @icon is retuning a blank value

That means when you open any other links, I presume it calls a different actions where your code for @icon is not getting called and it is nil.

if you want @icon to be available for all the actions. You have to probably do it in a before action where you call the method populating @icon

Comment: no its not blank at the first time  i run the server and its showing the exact icon there which i am expecting , the problem occurs when i open any other link in my app.

Comment: You must be sure `@icon` is in each view you load.